# Android layout dont succsed to locate

Tags: android, android-layout

I tried to do GridLayout in android ,but i didnt succsed to do that the buttons  be equals ,i want to do the Layout divide to 3 parts and in part will show 3 buttons , and the buttons will show all the screen.
someone can help me with code?

Comment: post your code that you have done so far.

Comment: I Just did RelativeLayout and i put buttons inside but it's didnt work out well.

Comment: why are you using RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

try this in your xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/gridview"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:columnWidth="90dp"
   android:numColumns="auto_fit"
   android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
   android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
   android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
   android:gravity="center"
/>
```

this will create a gridview with equal width to each col. you can set the number of columns by specifying the `numColumns` to required number.

To use LinearLayout you can set the Layout_weight for child views to equal value.

```
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv1"
   android:layout_width="0dp" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight = "1"/>

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv2"
   android:layout_width="0dp" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight = "1"/>

<TextView
   android:id="@+id/tv3"
   android:layout_width="0dp" 
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_weight = "1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You don't need to set the `weightSum` in parent layout just simply set the `layout_weight` in child and don't forget to set the width or height to 0dp in child views.

Set `layout_width` to `0dp` for horizontal and `layout_height` to `0dp` for vertical. and set the other to `match_parent` or `wrap_content` as required

Comment: If i want to do that with LinearLayout with weighsum,how i divide the screen to eqalus 3 parts ?

Comment: yes you can use LinearLayout for this as well. I'll add a short xml code in answer.